# Can't access my Vapor app from tutorial on my web server

Tags: nginx, vapor

I want to deploy a Vapor app on my server to use it as backend for my iOS app.

I'm pretty new to this topic. The only thing I did before was deploying a Django backend on the same server. I rebuild my server to set up the Vapor backend.

To begin, I wanted to deploy a Vapor app as basic as possible.
I followed this tutorial (it's short):
https://medium.com/@ankitank/deploy-a-basic-vapor-app-with-nginx-and-supervisor-1ef303320726

I followed the steps and didn't get errors.

The problem is, when I try to call `[IP]/hello` like in the tutorial, I get `502 Bad Gateway` as answer.

Nginx gives me this error:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: [IP], server: _, request: "GET /hello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", host: "[IP]"
```

I hope you can help me with this. :)

---

**Update 1:**

I changed the config to this:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  [DOMAIN];

    error_log   /var/log/[DOMAIN]_error.log warn;
    access_log  /var/log/[DOMAIN]_access.log;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    location / {
        # redirect all traffic to localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        # enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

        reset_timedout_connection on;

        tcp_nodelay on;

        client_max_body_size 10m;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|html|mp4)$ {
      access_log        off;
      expires           30d;
      root /home/[AppName]/Public;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I still get this one:

```
2019/12/01 14:48:04 [error] 6801#6801: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: [IP], server: [DOMAIN], request: "GET /hello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", host: [DOMAIN]
```

**Update 2:**

The error was related to this line:
`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;`

I had to change it to this:
`proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;`

It seems like localhost is not the same.

Now I can run the app via "vapor run" and I can access it. :)

Big thanks to @imike for all the help!!!

Comment: HAve you tried my config from your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105687/how-do-i-route-requests-to-my-vapor-app-using-nginx

Comment: Why did you deleted your question?

Comment: I've reposted my answer below

Comment: I deleted it, because I thought the question was not displaying my problem properly.

Comment: is your vapor app running while these tests? does it prints `Server starting on http://127.0.0.1:8080` in console?

Comment: first of all I'd suggest to run your vapor app with --hostname 0.0.0.0 argument and try to reach it like http://example.com:8080/hello and if it works then continue with nginx

Comment: Thank you very much!
If I run it via "swift run Run --hostname 0.0.0.0" I can access it.

If I run it normally via "vapor run" it shows "Server starting on http://localhost:8080", but I can't access it.

Comment: I guess that localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080 is not the same, so either try to replace in nginx config to localhost:8080 or start your app via "swift run Run --hostname 127.0.0.1"

Comment: and do not start your app on 0.0.0.0 cause in this case it may be reachable directly nginx and maybe used by not-good people to attack your app

Comment: Ahhhh, that's it. I changed "127.0.0.1:8080" to "localhost:8080" in my config and now I can access my server.
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try my 100% works production config with SSL and websockets support

```
server {
    listen  443;
    listen  [::]:443;
    server_name  mydomain.com;

    error_log   /var/log/mydomain.com_error.log warn;
    access_log  /var/log/mydomain.com_access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    location / {
        # redirect all traffic to localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        # enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

        reset_timedout_connection on;

        tcp_nodelay on;

        client_max_body_size 10m;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|html|mp4)$ {
      access_log        off;
      expires           30d;
      root /apps/myApp/Public;
    }
}
```

In the end of config you can see that static files from Public folder nginx will return directly without Vapor app running.

In your config.swift file you should use FileMiddleware only for macOS where you test the app without nginx cause this middleware is really slow, so I suggest you to put it into compiler check

```
#if os(macOS)
middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do I have to add SSL certificates to make this work?

Comment: Nginx won't restart when using your file. Do I have to do any special editing?

Comment: At least you should change the domain name. If you have no SSL then you should change the port from 443 to 80 and remove all lines related to SSL.

Comment: Thank you! I think I changed the SSL related lines and nginx restarts now. I unfortunately sill get a 502. I updated my question. Could you please take another look?

Answer (score 0):

The error was related to this line in the config file:
`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;`

I had to change it to this:
`proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;`

It seems like localhost was not the same.

Now I can run the app via "vapor run" and I can access it. :)

Big thanks to @imike for all the help! He solved it!