# Swift Vapor web sockets doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: swift, websocket, server, vapor, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trynna set up my server application on Ubuntu 22.04. Everything works except websocets. When I ran the server on my computer locally they worked. When I trynna connect via Postman, the connection is broken and I get the following message.[image]

[image]

I have tried making requests both through nginx and directly.
What this problem may be related to and how to solve it?

Comment: The 101 status code is perfectly valid and Postman should be handling that fine. Maybe it's a configuration option you can set, otherwise try a different websocket client

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59108754/19980152) helped me. (Some words for characters limit)